# Why overload the () operator (callable operator) in a C++ class or struct when you could use a constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, callable-object

Why would you overload the () operator in a C++ class or struct in C++11 or higher? As far as I can tell, these operators are overloaded when you want to pass objects like classes or structs into a std::thread and kick off a new thread with a package of data to go along with it, through a callable type.
But other than that, why else would you overload the () operator? Couldn't you simply do the same things in the constructor for a class or struct?

Why use

```
  struct MyCallableStruct{
    void operator() () {
        dosomething();
    }
  }
```

when you could do

```
  struct MyCallableStruct{
      MyCallableStruct() { dosomething(); }
  }
```

Comment: They have very different effect.

Comment: The whole point of `operator()` is to make an object look and act like a function. Yes, if you ignore the point of a feature, then the feature has no point. But if you don't start from the perspective that the intended point of a feature can be ignored, then... well, there's the point. I don't understand your question.

Comment: Those two contexts are completely different. The former doesn't actually execute *anything*; it only declares an operator that *can*. The latter *always* executes on construction. If that fits your usage pattern, so be it, but they're very different things.

Comment: One is so the object can be used as a functor, the other happens upon object construction.  A constructed object that has a functor can be called over and over.  A constructed object is constructed once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're totally different.

First and most importantly,  When you use **operator()**, it can be **passed as function parameters** (by object).
In contrast, when implemented by **constructor**, it can only be **passed through templates** (by class)

Second, operator() can be called several times after object created,
while construtor can only be called at constructing

All in all, they're different and useful in different scenarios

Comment: Correct but you might want to clarify "by object"/"by class" which is unclear unless you know already know C++ well enough to know the answer.

Comment: I understand the usage now. Incidentally I now realize the difference of "by object" and "by class"